# Why will my profile pictures not show up Django

Tags: python, django

So I am creating a small website, and I want users to be able to upload profile pictures to their page. However, I ran into a problem, and the image won't render. I have the actual process for the user to upload a profile picture, and it saves to a directory, but it won't load in the HTML document

I have looked online for answers, but have found none. I have tried renaming fields in the models.py file because I thought that it might be an issue where I need a certain field name. None of these worked

Here is the relevant UserProfileInfo model in models.py

```py
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True) #models.OneToOneField(User,'on_delete')#
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True) #models.OneToOneField(User,'on_delete')#
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',default='default.png')
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True,default=timezone.now)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Here is the views.py file for the user registration

```py
def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForms(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'image' in request.FILES:
                profile.image = request.FILES['image']

            profile.save()
            user.save()

            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForms()

    return render(request,'mainapp/registration.html',{'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered,})
```

And finally here is the profile.html

```html
{% extends 'mainapp/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{{ user.username }}
{{ user.joined_date }}
{% if user.userprofileinfo.image %}
                <img class="circular--square" src="{{ user.userprofileinfo.image.url }}" width="200" height="200">
            {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I want the profile picture to be displayed, however at the moment, the default placeholder of when an image isn't displayed properly shows up. Thanks :)

Comment: Can we see the source code of the template rendered in the browser? Is it not generating the image URL? Is the image URL broken?

Comment: So where the image is supposed to be, the default placeholder for an image which doesn't work is shown. In the chrome dev tools, it is saying that the image source, is in fact the source of the image.
This is what it says in chrome
`<img class="circular--square" src="mainapp/media/profile_pics/Untitled-1_c6duQ7L.png" width="200" height="200">`

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the line

```
{% load static %}
```

in the base template extended by profile.html ? It is necessary to include this line at the start to render images and other static files. Also have you set the static_url as '/static/' as mentioned here [django static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if images are properly saved in the media folder but not loading properly? Check `mainapp/media/profile_pics` folder again.

I think there is a loop in `UserProfileInfo.save()` function. You are loading image in `save()` function with `Image.open(self.image.path)` while it is not properly saved yet and only a temporary file is saved without any contents.

Comment: The images are getting saved properly. I can go to the folder, and the images are there.